# Filter first item in Observable

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-observable

I have the following component:

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  user$: Observable<UserModel>;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.user$ = this.getUser();

  }

  getUser(): Observable<UserModel> {

    return this.userService.getByUserId(25).pipe(map((payload: Payload<UserResponse>) => {

      return payload.result.map((response: UserResponse) => { 

        return {
          id: response.id,
          name: response.name,
          // Other mapping properties
        };

      });

    }));

  }
}
```

With my code `getUser()` should return a `Observable<UserModel[]>`.

But I know that in this case payload has only one UserResponse.

So I would like `getUser()` method to return `Observable<UserModel>`.

How to adjust the pipe / map code to return an Observable of one UserModel?

**Payload**

Payload is:

```
export class Payload<T> {

  errors: Error[];
  paging: Paging;
  result: T[];

  constructor(result: T[], paging?: Paging, errors?: Error[]) {

    this.errors = errors;
    this.paging = paging;
    this.result = result;

  }

}
```

Comment: maybe you want to use `switchMap` but im not actually sure what are you asking for. `switchMap` will "switch" context to what you return in that `map` callback so it wont be as nested as it is now.

Comment: The part return this.userService.getByUserId(25) ... returns an Observable<UserDetailModel[]> but since I know the response has only one item I need the getUser() to return Observable<UserDetailModel>. Do you understand?

Comment: more or less. Pobably you want `switchMap`

Comment: pipe(map(payload=>payload[0]))?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I'm not sure why you need two maps... if you just want to map your server response to some other model for the client, one map should be sufficient. Are you looking to map your server response to a new object?

Comment: there is a `first` operator to only emit the first value from the source: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/first

Comment: @Phil Yes I am mapping it to a new object

Comment: @fridoo I tried first after pipe but in fact the array is in payload.result. I added Payload code to my question,

Comment: I also tried 'payload.result.slice(0, 1).map((response:' but it does not compile.

Comment: Just create the object you want to return from the first element in the array then`payload.result[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood as your API sends only one entity and you need to map this one to get Observable 
And also as I see UserResponse interface isn't equal to UserModel. So you need to map first element of an array to take only `[0]` and also you UserModel props:

```
getUser(): Observable<UserModel> {

    return this.userService.getByUserId(25)
      .pipe(
        map((payload: Payload<UserResponse>) => ({id:payload.result[0], name: payload.result[0].name})
      );

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to map a server response that is nested in a `results` property to a new object, you want to map to the `results` property, and then map again to return the new object. Something like this:

```
getUser(userId): Observable<UserDetailModel> {

    return this.userService.getByUserId(userId).pipe(
      map(payload => payload.result[0])
      map(result => {
        return {
          id: result.id,
          name: result.name,
          // Other mapping properties
        };

    }));

  }
```

Comment: `payload.result` is an array, so this shouldn't work out. But mapping the Observable twice looks good and makes the OPs code cleaner I would say.